# React native fetch url endcoded

Tags: reactjs, react-native, localhost

Does anyone know what the problem is with the below code? Because currently i can get only 1 data from the db but when the db has 2 data or 3 data then it will show the following error message:

> JSON Parse error : Unable to parse JSON String

```html
 componentDidMount(){

const packid = 'this.props.navigation.getParam'('packid');

    return fetch('http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/User_Project/packages_List_klcc.php?packid='+packid, {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
}
}).then((response) => response.json())
           .then((responseJson) => {
             console.log(responseJson)
             this.setState({
               isLoading: false,
               dataklcc: responseJson
             }, function() {
               // In this block you can do something with new state.
             });
           })
       .catch((error) => {

             console.error(error);
           });

   }
```

Comment: Please analyse and provide actual data that you are getting from the server i.e. `response` before you do `response.json()` . You might be able to debug it from there only.

Comment: return fetch('http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/User_Project/packages_List_klcc.php?packid='+packid, which mean this line of code only send data to server but not retrieve data right? suraj malviya